# how to pass DB values to CSS file in laravel 5.4

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5.4

Is it possible to pass  Table values to style.css file because i want to change Cover image which is background-image dynmicallay?

i tried the following code by **Internal Css** its worked perfect.. but i want it on **External Css** .

```css
<style>
    .timeline-cover{
        background: url('<?php if (isset($userinfo[0]['cover'])) { echo url('images/users/'. $userinfo[0]['cover']);} else { echo url('images/cover/1.jpg');}?>') no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="timeline-cover"></div>
```

Comment: This is getting dated, please select an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you must have 2 external files I suggest you have 2 css files, one permanent with the main styling and the second written dynamically by the controller before calling the view, overwriting or adding to css classes defined in the former.
This is not the most efficient however as you are constantly writing to file.

suggest have a permanent style sheet with:

```
.timeline-cover{
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and have the controller create a $bgu variable depending on required logic in the controller then as you have been in the view:

```
.timeline-cover{
    background: url('<?php echo $bgu ?>') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
 $('.timeline-cover').append("<style>"+
        ".timeline-cover"+
        "{"+
          "background: url('<?php if (isset($userinfo[0]['cover'])) { echo url('images/users/'. $userinfo[0]['cover']);} else { echo url('images/cover/1.jpg');}?>') no-repeat;"+
            "background-position: center;"+
           " background-size: cover;"+
        "}"+
    "</style>");
```

Comment: This uses jquery to create markup that can be written directly - whats the point in that ? And it simply creates current markup, so nothing has changed ?

Comment: This is quite old - maybe select an answer or advise why its not the correct answer